# Upload video to Twitter using ios + Social.framework + Twitter.framework

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, twitter

How do I upload video to Twitter using my ios application. Like vine app did it for them. i know that vine is a twitter app. Whether there is any way to do it for other third party app also?.

Please help on this

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible that to share Videos on Twitter ,
   There are no framework for uploading videos on twitter.
   You just upload Images and update your status only with social framework....

Answer (score 1):

You can upload video to twitter by using the new API. I have tried it, it works.

Please check this: https://github.com/liu044100/SocialVideoHelper

You just need to call this class method.

```
+(void)uploadTwitterVideo:(NSData*)videoData account:(ACAccount*)account withCompletion:(dispatch_block_t)completion;
```

Hope it can resolve your problem.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out TwitterVideoUpload https://github.com/mtrung/TwitterVideoUpload

- Support chunk upload for > 5MB video file
- Built-in support for user's credential retrieval
- Support tweet text along with video